# SVG not working on Mobile Safari when in web-app-capable mode

Tags: ios, mobile, svg, safari, iphone-web-app

I can load the page and have SVG working just fine on both Mobile and Desktop versions of Safari, but when I add the page the home screen to remove the browser chrome and give the app a more native feel, the SVGs do not load. Everything else loads just fine, and when I use PNG instead of SVG those load in web app mode. Anyone ever run into this issue or know of a way to fix it?